# What’s the word for forced fun?

Tags: single-word-requests

Forced fun would be the dreaded company outing with icebreakers and other group activities meant for enjoyment but often achieve the opposite. But, what is a single word that defines this?

- *The major drawback in working for *ElboniaCo* was the unavoidable requirement to participate in the company's ill-conceived ______ activities.*

Comment: If there’s not a word for that, there should be. Unfortunately, “they” don’t like people making up new words around here. But you can try to further your cause by editing your question to show an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank ____ where this word would go.

Comment: *Teambuilding* has that implication

Comment: @TinfoilHat I believe that a sample sentence is widely considered to be a requirement for SWR questions, as mentioned in [that tag's description](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan — Yes, it is. I’m just trying to hint that adding a sample sentence might extend the question’s life, but it might not prevent its closure. It’s worth a try, though.

Comment: @Stuart F It probably works even without scare quotes.

Comment: @Stuart F or what about 'bonding'? You don't think that is exactly what Ed Ash is surreptitiously trying to achieve?

Comment: No; I was surreptitiously offering the opinion that the ironic/sarcastic sense of 'teambuilding' is sadly so common that the word's scare-quotes era is probably over. Has 'bonding' become as pejorative?

Comment: Kate Morgan, in a [BBC Worklife article {2022}](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20220517-the-death-of-mandatory-fun-in-the-office), comes up with nothing tighter than _forced fun_, _forced ‘fun’ activities_, and 'mandatory fun' (scare quotes but not italics hers).

Answer (score 1):

That word would be ***fundatory***.

It hasn’t hit the big books (let’s say, the *Oxford English Dictionary*<sup>*</sup>) yet, but it *can* be found in the wild.

Here’s a sentence from [*The ECoaching Continuum for Educators —
Using Technology to Enrich Professional Development and Improve Student Outcomes* (Marcia L. Rock, 2019)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_eCoaching_Continuum_for_Educators/n5KwDwAAQBAJ):

> *Most teachers, other school professionals, administrators, and eCoaches agree that **all should guard against the perils of mandated
> fun, also known as “fundatory” activities**, and focus instead on
> engaging in authentic, meaningful enterprises that help learning team
> members work well togwther in better meeting the needs of the whole
> child.*
>
> <sub>[Preview
> here](https://books.google.com/books?id=n5KwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=%22Most+teachers,+other+school+professionals,+administrators,+and+eCoaches+agree+that+all+should+guard+against+the+perils+of+mandated+fun,+also+known+as+%E2%80%9Cfundatory%E2%80%9D+activities,+and+focus+instead+on+engaging+in+authentic%22&source=bl&ots=hF-7MALTXT&sig=ACfU3U3ByhWMmy8XL9ZxnTJzpNMwTNHyRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirz9mikbD_AhWlhu4BHUjnAyYQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Most%20teachers%2C%20other%20school%20professionals%2C%20administrators%2C%20and%20eCoaches%20agree%20that%20all%20should%20guard%20against%20the%20perils%20of%20mandated%20fun%2C%20also%20known%20as%20%E2%80%9Cfundatory%E2%80%9D%20activities%2C%20and%20focus%20instead%20on%20engaging%20in%20authentic%22&f=false)</sub>

Also be sure to check out [Urban Dictionary entries for *fundatory*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fundatory):

> *any event or function that is intended to be fun, but is mandatory and will most likely suck*
>
> *mandatory fun activities that happen at work, which are never actually fun at all*

Who knows? Maybe the *OED* will offer your own sentence as an early example usage someday.

---

<sub>* Therein **can** be found the “now rare” word *fundatory* (*relating to the founding of something*), but that’s not this.</sub>